# i am new to python i am trying to make a bmi calculator

Tags: python, new-operator, bmi

```
w=int(input("Enter your weight"))
h=int(input("Enter your height"))
bmi=w/h**2
if (bmi<=18.5):
    print("UnderWeight")
elif (bmi>18.5 and   bmi<=24.9):
    print("Healthy")
elif (bmi>=25 and bmi<=29.9):
    print("OverWeight")
elif (bmi>30):
    print("Obese")
```

the output is not accurate
weight is measured in kgs and height is measured in centimeters
please help!

its like weight 65 kgs and height 150 cms it shows under weight it is supposed to be overweight or healthy

Comment: its like weight 65 kgs and height 150 cms it shows under weight it is supposed to be overweight or healthy

Answer (score 3):

For BMI height needs to be in meters and not centimetres . So just make this change

```py
bmi = w / (h/100)**2
```

or

```py
h /= 100 # or h = h / 100
bmi = w / h**2
```

Comment: You're welcome! I'd appreciate it if you accept my answer =)

Comment: it really helped